# Looking for forum engine that is easy to integrate with existing user tables

Tags: python, forum, forums

I have a custom made web-site in Python/MySQL with custom user/session tables and users already using it.

I am looking for forum to integrate with the current site:

Users of the main site should automatically get an account and get logged into forum. They would just pick a different visible name for the forum (no email verification, no password / recovery question, and so on)

I have searched the net for hours. Couldn't find any proper (well maintained, well used) forum code in python to use. So I am ready to resort to running a PHP forum in parallel ...

Any recommendation on which forum to use to avoid a major reverse engineering for the single sign-on and integrated login process? (I am no good in PHP, so I prefer to add code to our site rather than mess around with the PHP codes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with [Simple Machines Forum](http://www.simplemachines.org/). It provides a set of [integration hooks](http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=173483.0).

With a bit of php hacking, you can connect it to anything you want.

SMF 2.0 is still in beta, but get much more control on customization. T

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Nearforums](http://nearforums.codeplex.com): it is developed in .NET (C#), it uses a MySQL database, runs on IIS or Apache webservers (thanks to Mono) and your users can sign in with their existing users credentials (You will have to expose a openid provider on your main site). See the full features to see if it fits your requirements.

Disclaimer: I am a developer of nearforums

Comment: Not exactly related to the topic, but I haven't found another way to cast people's help: @jorgebg, would you mind getting a look at this please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653030/how-to-integrate-nearforums-in-my-current-mvc-app -- many thanks